# S4 Mini GT-i9192 Roll back from Lollipop 5.1 to Kitkat 4.4.2

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini

I've installed unofficial lollipop ver 5.1 cynogen on S4 mini GT-i9192 recently.its good but there are some bugs and flip cover doesnt shows clock,notifications. 
so I want to rollback to original kitkat 4.4.2.

How can I do that?
 Pls help me out.

I just backup my data through kies 3 before install,that's it. No Nandroid backup

Thanks

Comment: Find and flash the Kitkat ROM. How did you flash the Lollipop one at first place?

Comment: Thanks for reply.              Unofficial lollipop firmware.        I flash it, by the steps mentioned in xda . 1)i rooted my mobile 2)Cleared all caches from reboot menu   2)install zip from sdcard (OS and GAPPS) both.

Comment: This time, boot into **custom Recovery**, clear /data, /cache, /system and then flash the ROM zip meant for KitKat. Reboot and done!

Comment: Thanks again. OK .    is there any solution for flip cover issue in lollipop

Comment: That would be a different thing to talk about and it would make us astray from the real topic which is rolling back to KitKat. Please ask a new question for that. Before doing that make sure to read  [How do I ask a good question?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)